# Modules in sub-package cannot import eachother when referenced from top

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am digging myself into a deep hole on this topic.

I have a project structed like this

```
main.py
data/
   __init__.py
   api.py
   report.py
```

`api.py` imports `report.py`

In `main.py` I have:

```
from data.api import class1, class2
```

and I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'report'`

From searching on SO I understand that there are `sys.path` manipulations you can do to make the python path execute at a different level but from my reading that is considered **code smell**.

One solution could be that I just put the report class into `api.py` but then what is the point of all of python's module and package capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SO for being apart of the whiteboarding of my question haha.

My problem here is that the modules in `data/` were not told to look locally for the other modules that they reference.

In `api.py` I changed

`import report`

to
`import .report`

Now `main.py` imports everything correctly!